# Removing a folder from multiple img src tags with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a site with many different gallery categories that display a smaller thumbnail size until the screen width is below 1200px, after which I would like to display the full size instead.

The images are displayed like so:

```
<section class="gallery category1">
    <img id="cat1img1" src="cat1/small/img-1.jpg" alt="blah">
    <img id="cat1img2" src="cat1/small/img-2.jpg" alt="blah">
    etc...
</section>
<section class="gallery category2">
    <img id="cat2img1" src="cat2/small/img-1.jpg" alt="blah">
    <img id="cat2img2" src="cat2/small/img-2.jpg" alt="blah">
    etc...
</section>
```

And all I want to do is use a JS media query with some jQuery to remove the "small/" from each tag without listing every single img so they can be freely added and removed without modifying the code again.

This is what I've tried but it's not changing the img url, though it does trigger my size change check:

```
function galleryBreak(x) {
    if (x.matches) {
        $('.gallery').children('img').attr('src').replace('/small','')
        console.log('size change check');
    };
};
var x=window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)')
galleryBreak(x)
x.addListener(galleryBreak)
```

Comment: Where does `addListener()` get defined?

Comment: Not sure, got it from here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple (2) galleries and multiple images. You need to iterate over all images for all galleries. Something like this

```js
function changeImagePaths(theGallery) {
  var images = theGallery.querySelectorAll('img');
  images.forEach( image => {
      console.log('Path before: ', image.src)
      image.src = image.src.replace('/small','')
      console.log('Path AFTER: ', image.src)
  });
};

var x=window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)')
var myGalleries = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery')
myGalleries.forEach( gallery => {
    if(x.matches) {
      changeImagePaths(gallery)
    }
});
```

```html
<section class="gallery category1">
    <img id="img1" src="cat1/small/img-1.jpg" alt="blah">
    <img id="img2" src="cat1/small/img-2.jpg" alt="blah">
</section>
<section class="gallery category2">
    <img id="img1" src="cat2/small/img-1.jpg" alt="blah">
    <img id="img2" src="cat2/small/img-2.jpg" alt="blah">
</section>
```

[JsFiddle to play with here](https://jsfiddle.net/L5su346z/)

Now all of that said, if you can change the HTML please use [Responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) which will show you all you need can be set right in the image tag like:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 1.5x,
             elva-fairy-640w.jpg 2x"
     src="elva-fairy-640w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

Comment: Thanks, both work but I'll just bite the bullet on restructuring my file system to use responsive images as you're right that it's the better option, I was being lazy

Answer (score 1):

add `resize` event listener on window so that on each window / browser resize this event will be fired

```js
const galleryBreak = () => {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)').matches) {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img');
    Array.from(images).forEach(img => {
      const imgSrc = img.src.replace('/small', '');
      img.src = imgSrc;
      console.log(imgSrc);
    });
  }
};

window.addEventListener('resize', galleryBreak);
```